# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' Error in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

Im really new to the flutter and stuck at this point im designing the uber clone but not able to get the searched place details and also the `polyline` is not coming only the `progress bar` its get stuck over there only loading loading.....

```
E/flutter (20208): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (20208): #0      HelperMethods.getDirectionDetails (package:cab_rider/helpers/helpermethods.dart:85:22)
E/flutter (20208): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20208): #1      _MainPageState.getDirection (package:cab_rider/mainpage.dart:349:23)
E/flutter (20208): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20208): #2      _MainPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:cab_rider/mainpage.dart:243:29)
E/flutter (20208): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20208):
```

This is my `HelperMethods.dart` file code :

```
import 'package:cab_rider/datamodels/address.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/datamodels/directiondetails.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/dataprovider/appdata.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/globalvariable.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/helpers/requesthelper.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HelperMethods{


  static Future<String> findCordinateAddress(Position position, context) async {
    String placeAddress = '';
    String st1, st2, st3, st4;

    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    if (connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.mobile && connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      return placeAddress;
    }

    String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng= ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}&key=$mapKey';

    var response = await RequestHelper.getRequest(url);

    if(response != 'failed'){
      placeAddress = response['results'][0]['formatted_address'];


      var placeId;
      var longitude;
      var latitude;
      var placeFormattedAddress;
      var placeName;

      st1 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"];
      st2 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][1]["long_name"];
      st3 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][2]["long_name"];
      st4 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][3]["long_name"];
      placeAddress = st1 + ", " + st2 + ", " + st3 + ", " + st4;

      Address pickupAddress = new Address(placeId: placeId , longitude: longitude, latitude: latitude, placeFormattedAddress: placeFormattedAddress, placeName: placeName);
      pickupAddress.longitude = position.longitude;
      pickupAddress.latitude = position.latitude;
      pickupAddress.placeName = placeAddress;


      Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).updatePickupAddress(pickupAddress);



    }

    return placeAddress;
  }

  static Future<DirectionDetails?> getDirectionDetails(LatLng startPosition, LatLng endPosition) async {

    String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${startPosition.latitude},${startPosition.longitude}&destination=${endPosition.latitude},${endPosition.longitude}&mode=driving&key=$mapKey';

    var response = await RequestHelper.getRequest(url);                  //errorline 

    if(response == 'failed'){
      return null;
    }

    var durationText;
    var durationValue;
    var distanceText;
    var distanceValue;
    var encodedPoints;


    DirectionDetails directionDetails = DirectionDetails(distanceText: distanceText, distanceValue: distanceValue, durationText: durationText, durationValue: durationValue, encodedPoints: encodedPoints);


    directionDetails.durationText = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['text'];
    directionDetails.durationValue = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value'];         //error line

    directionDetails.distanceText = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'];
    directionDetails.distanceValue = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value'];

    directionDetails.encodedPoints = response['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'] ;

    return directionDetails;
  }
}
```

This is my `MainPage.dart` file code: -

```
import 'package:cab_rider/brand_colors.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/dataprovider/appdata.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/helpers/helpermethods.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/searchpage.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/styles/styles.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/widgets/BrandDivider.dart';
import 'package:cab_rider/widgets/ProgressDialog.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:outline_material_icons/outline_material_icons.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id ='mainpage';


  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  double searchSheetHeight = (Platform.isIOS) ? 300 : 275 ;


  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  double mapBottomPadding = 0;

  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
   Position? currentPosition;

    void setupPositionLocator() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
    currentPosition = position;


    LatLng pos = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition(target: pos, zoom: 14);
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cp));

    String address = await HelperMethods.findCordinateAddress(position, context);
    print(address);


  }

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
      zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Container(
        width: 250,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Drawer(

          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            children: <Widget>[
              
              Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                height: 160,
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('images/user_icon.png', height: 60, width: 60,),
                      SizedBox(width: 15,),

                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Shubham',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Brand-Bold'),),
                          SizedBox(height: 5,),
                          Text('View Profile'),

                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                ),
              ),
              BrandDivider(),

              SizedBox(height: 10,),

              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(OMIcons.cardGiftcard),
                title: Text('Free Rides', style: kDrawerItemStyle,),
              ),

              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(OMIcons.creditCard),
                title: Text('Payments', style: kDrawerItemStyle,),
              ),

              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(OMIcons.history),
                title: Text('Ride History', style: kDrawerItemStyle,),
              ),

              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(OMIcons.contactSupport),
                title: Text('Support', style: kDrawerItemStyle,),
              ),

              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(OMIcons.info),
                title: Text('About', style: kDrawerItemStyle,),
              )

            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),

        body:Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: mapBottomPadding),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,

              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
                _controller.complete(controller);
                mapController = controller;


                setState(() {

                  mapBottomPadding  = (Platform.isAndroid) ? 280 : 270 ;
                });

                setupPositionLocator();

              },


            ),

            /// MenuButton
            Positioned(
              top: 44,
              left: 20,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                },
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                       color: Colors.black26,
                        blurRadius: 5.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.5,
                        offset: Offset(
                          0.7,
                          0.7,
                        ),

                      )
                    ]
                  ),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    radius: 20,
                    child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black87,),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),


            /// SearchSheet
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: searchSheetHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 15.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(
                        0.7,
                        0.7,
                      )

                    )
                  ]


                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 18),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 5,),
                      Text('Nice to see you!', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),
                      Text('Where are you going?', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Brand-Bold'),),

                      SizedBox(height: 20,),

                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {

                          var response = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SearchPage()
                          ));

                          if(response == 'getDirection'){

                            await getDirection();                                      // error line
                          }

                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                blurRadius: 5.0,
                                spreadRadius: 0.5,
                                offset: Offset(
                                  0.7,
                                  0.7,
                                )
                              )
                            ]
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.blueAccent,),
                                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                Text('Search Destination'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 22,),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(OMIcons.home, color: BrandColors.colorDimText,),
                          SizedBox(width: 12,),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Add Home'),
                              SizedBox(height: 3,),
                              Text('Your residental address ',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: BrandColors.colorDimText,),

                              ),
                            ]
                          )

                        ],
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      BrandDivider(),

                      SizedBox(height: 16,),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(OMIcons.workOutline, color: BrandColors.colorDimText,),
                          SizedBox(width: 12,),
                          Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Add Work'),
                                SizedBox(height: 3,),
                                Text('Your Office address ',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: BrandColors.colorDimText,),

                                ),
                              ]
                          )

                        ],
                      ),



                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      );


  }

   Future<void> getDirection() async {

    var pickup = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).pickupAddress;
    var destination = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).destinationAddress;

    var pickLatLng = LatLng(pickup!.latitude, pickup.longitude);
    var destinationLatLng = LatLng(destination!.latitude, destination.longitude);

    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => ProgressDialog(status: 'Please wait',)
    );

    var thisDetails = await HelperMethods.getDirectionDetails(pickLatLng, destinationLatLng);

    Navigator.pop(context);

    print(thisDetails!.encodedPoints);


  }
}
```

This is my `RequestHelper.dart` file :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class RequestHelper{

 static Future<dynamic> getRequest(String url) async {


   http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

   try {
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       String data = response.body;
       var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
       return decodedData;
     } else {
       return 'failed';
     }
   } catch (e) {
     return 'failed';
   }

 }
}
```

#1 error points out at this line

```
directionDetails.durationText = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['text'];
    directionDetails.durationValue = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value'];         //error line

    directionDetails.distanceText = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'];
    directionDetails.distanceValue = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value'];

    directionDetails.encodedPoints = response['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'] ;
```

#2 error points out this line

```
var response = await RequestHelper.getRequest(url);
```

#3 error points out this line

```
await getDirection();
```

Please help me to solve this error its my final year project...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng= ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}&key=$mapKey';`

use

`String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng= ${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}&key=$mapKey';`

and

Instead of

`String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${startPosition.latitude},${startPosition.longitude}&destination=${endPosition.latitude},${endPosition.longitude}&mode=driving&key=$mapKey';`

use

`String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${startPosition.latitude},${startPosition.longitude}&destination=${endPosition.latitude.toString()},${endPosition.longitude.toString()}&mode=driving&key=$mapKey';`

You have to convert longitude and latitude to String values using `toString()` method before concatenating!

Comment: sorry Dulaj its not working either same error is coming same 3 asynchronous suspension error please can you provide another solution

Answer (score 0):

using [google_directions_api](https://pub.dev/packages/google_directions_api) saved me while dealing with direction

Answer (score 0):

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

It seems you declare a **Variable** as an **Int** on the server-side make that **Variable as String** the problem will be resolve.

Comment: can you please be more specific sir what should i do